# What is the best way how to obtain a list of images hosted on a Scene 7 server?

Tags: angularjs, adobe, scene7

I am working on an (angular 1) application feature that has to display a list of images that are available for user to select (for whatever purpose).

It is all very trivial, except that the images are hosted on a [Scene 7](http://www.adobe.com/marketing-cloud/enterprise-content-management/assets-on-demand.html) 
server. I know there is concept of image sets. Presumably a set would be created there and all I would need to do is to obtain the list of images in that set and parse it into a javascript array.

However, after some looking through docs and searching the web, I am no wiser how to achieve that.

How would one go about achieving this end? Getting a list of available images from Scene 7 server and passing that to an angular appliation?

In an ideal case, that would be in JSON format and with frontend-only approach. However, if that is impossible, then other approaches would do too. Say, an angular call to own backend server that would connect to Scene 7 API, obtain that list in whatever shape or format, parse it and then pass it as JSON to angular app.

Has anyone had experience with this?

Answer (score -1):

If supported, could develop an API that retrieves the image Urls from the Image Server.